# How to wrap script tag into cdata in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

How to wrap:

```
<script> if (typeof ty === "undefined") { var ty = { chainOnLoad: function(onLoadHandler..</script>
```

to this:

```
//<![CDATA[<script> if (typeof ty === "undefined") { var ty = { chainOnLoad:  function(onLoadHandler.. </script>//]]>
```

How to do this?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: Where does the tag exist? With other tags? Or in a standalone string?

Answer (score 0):

You could take your chances with this

Find `(<(?:script(?:\s+(?>"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|(?:(?!/>)[^>])?)+)?\s*>)[\S\s]*?</script\s*>)`

Replace `<![CDATA[$1]]>`

However, the problem is that browsers parse CDATA as `<![CDATA[[`*[\S\s]*?*`]]>`
which means you have to process $1 ( *.here.* ) for the `]]>`
sequence, then do something to mitigate it.

Otherwise the cdata will terminate early, leaving residual junk in there.

Note that you can't just find CDATA without finding *all* tags on a first
come/serve basis.
The reason is that CDATA, like any tag can be hidden inside other constructs.

In general, the expression to parse *all* tags is this

`<(?:(?:(?:(script|style|object|embed|applet|noframes|noscript|noembed)(?:\s+(?>"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|(?:(?!/>)[^>])?)+)?\s*>)[\S\s]*?</\1\s*(?=>))|(?:/?[\w:]+\s*/?)|(?:[\w:]+\s+(?:"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|[^>]?)+\s*/?)|\?[\S\s]*?\?|(?:!(?:(?:DOCTYPE[\S\s]*?)|(?:\[CDATA\[[\S\s]*?\]\])|(?:--[\S\s]*?--)|(?:ATTLIST[\S\s]*?)|(?:ENTITY[\S\s]*?)|(?:ELEMENT[\S\s]*?))))>`

You'd start out by writing back non-script tags, when you get a script tag
do your substitution.